# Catch ActiveDirectory "addUser" Event in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory

We have the ability of "AutoLogin" in our systems.

So if I create a new user in AD as "John" - then John has the ability to access the intranet web site ( we query AD to see if the current user is in AD).

**But**

We also have a `users` table (SQL Server) which needs to have the `FirstName` and `LastName` of the new user.

We want to update that `Users` table each time a new user in AD is created - some C# code should be run to enter the relevant data into SQL Server (and some other things).

HOw can I catch the event of "new user in AD created"  ?

Comment: How are those users in AD created?? Using the default AD (Active Directory Users & Computers) tools?? Or a custom app of your own making?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Ryan Dunn's excellent blog post:

[Implementing Change Notifications in .NET](http://dunnry.com/blog/ImplementingChangeNotificationsInNET.aspx)

that deals with this exact topic. He offers three options:

- Polling for Changes using uSNChanged
- Polling for Changes Using the DirSync Control
- Change Notifications in Active Directory

and shows pros and cons for each of the options, and some C# code for the third option (Change Notifications).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](http://Introduction%20to%20System.DirectoryServices.Protocols).DirectoryNotificationControl from C# for this purpose so you don't have to poll AD for changes.

WMI is perhaps a second solution you can dig in.It exists AD WMI Providers. [Using WMI to Monitor AD](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-management-instrumentation-wmi/using-wmi-to-monitor-ad) gives you some clues about that. This article don't do more than what you get so far, but I think that with WMI events you can create the notifications you need. You can find Microsoft informations about this begining in [Monitoring Active Directory Health](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180912.aspx), [especialy Active Directory WMI Providers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180914.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you can capture that kind of event without wrapping the actual function of adding the new user into some kind of c# routine. If you go down this route, you can add the used to AD and mysql at the same time.

Another option would be to poll the AD users and check this against the existing mysql users and add new when found.